# How to display Highlighted text using Solrj

Tags: solrj

I am new to Solr and SolrJ. I am trying to use for a desktop application and I have files(text files) to index and search. I wanted to use highlight feature and display the fragments with highlight,but I don't get them to display in yellow background as you highlight a text, please let me know how to display the text in yellow background.

here is my code snippet:

```
public void TestHighLight(SolrQuery query) throws 
              SolrServerException, IOException {
    query.setQuery("*");
    query.set("hl", "true");
    query.set("hl.snippets", "5");
    query.set("q", "text:Pune");
    query.set("hl.fl", "*");
    QueryResponse queryResponse = client.query(query);
    SolrDocumentList docs = queryResponse.getResults();
    Iterator  iter = docs.iterator(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < docs.size(); i++) {
        iter = docs.get(i).getFieldNames().iterator();
        String fldVal = (String) docs.get(i).getFieldValue("id");
        String docID = (String) docs.get(i).get("id");
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            String highlighText = getHighlightedText(queryResponse, 
            "text", docID);
            System.out.println(" tHighlightedText is "  + highlighText );
        }
    }
}
```

The output looks like this:how do I color it ? 
[ for Java Developer at *Pune*

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Set the pre and post parameters of the highlighter. Specifies the “tag” to use before a highlighted term. This can be any string, but is most often an HTML or XML tag.

e.g:

```
solrQueryHandler.setHighlightSimplePre("<font color="yellow">");
solrQueryHandler.setHighlightSimplePost("/font");
```

But note that this will work only for the Original Highlighter